# How do you implement custom inline searching in an ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, search, listbox, itemscontrol

This is a two-parter.

First, in WPF the standard ListBox control automatically supports inline searching of its items.  It does this via using the items' ToString function, meaning if you have the focus inside a listbox and just start typing, it will do a left-most search, highlighting any items whose ToString matches what you've typed. Subsequent key presses within a short period of time add to the search string (i.e. typing 'A' followed by 'S' will left-search for 'AS' whereas typign 'A' then pausing, then typing 'S' will instead left-search for 'S'.

The problem is this mechanism seems to be dependent solely on the value returned by ToString, which in some cases is something we can't rely on.  Is there something else we can use instead of ToString?

The second part of this is that behavior only seems to be present in a ListBox, but no other ItemsControl objects (or hierarchical ones like a TreeView.)  Without having to re-write that functionality from scratch, is there an easy way to add it to an ItemsControl?

Comment: I'd say no. `ListBox`es most usually have text in them, so that functionality is logical, but `ItemsControl`s are generally meant to have objects in them and so default search functionality in an `ItemsControl` is less logical. You just need to do some basic filtering of your data... it should take more than 10 lines of code or so, so it's not difficult.

Comment: What about the first part of my question... which would help address the second part.  And your response completely ignores data templates which are regularly used with ListBoxes.  Even using DisplayMember will implicitly create a data template out of sync with ToString rendering that functionality potentially useless let alone confusing to a user who's getting odd selection (not filtering) behavior and they don't know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can control what is searched with `TextSearch.Text` or `TextSearch.TextPath` attached properties. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textsearch(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can apply `TextSearch.TextPath` to your `ListBox` instance (so it searches this property instead of `ToString`) or you can apply `TextSearch.Text` to individual `ListBoxItem` child (so you can set individual search text for individual elements).

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Items" XPath="People">
            <x:XData>
                <People xmlns="">
                    <Person Name="John" Surname="Smith" />
                    <Person Name="Andrew" Surname="Johnson" />
                    <Person Name="Otis" Surname="Everett" />
                    <Person Name="Jesus" Surname="Osborn" />
                </People>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Searches by a property (Name):" />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Items}, XPath=*}"
                 TextSearch.TextPath="@Name">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Run Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}" /> <Run Text="{Binding XPath=@Surname}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <TextBlock>Searches by a individual value (number in english):</TextBlock>
        <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem TextSearch.Text="One">1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem TextSearch.Text="Two">2</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem TextSearch.Text="Three">3</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem TextSearch.Text="Four">4</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

This behavior is implemented in the `ItemsControl` class (and you can find other examples of `ItemsControl` descendants with search: `ComboBox`, `DataGrid`). You can set `IsTextSearchEnabled` property to true to make it work. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.istextsearchenabled(v=vs.110).aspx)

The single level search works for `TreeView`. I think you should implement the search programmatically if you want  to perform multi level search. (see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e6d58fcc-4eaa-4bdc-8621-ce24c8efd330/treeview-textsearch)